# "Expression must have class type" using undocumented library function

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having this error trying to understand how to implement [this constructor](http://mbed.org/users/feb11/code/Crypto/file/f04410cef037/cipher/AES.cpp).

I stripped the call out of the function I did have it in, and reached a pretty minimal demonstration of my issue:

```
uint32_t p=0, c;
uint8_t k=0x00;
c = p.AES::AES(AES_128, k);
```

I expect the plaintext `p` to be encrypted by AES with key `k` to ciphertext `c`.

Instead, I get the error `Expression must have class type`, due to my inexperience with OOP no doubt.

Unfortunately the library is not well documented at all, so I cannot even learn by example (without the help of SO!) - what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple problems: First that you use `p` as an object, but it's a variable of a primitive type. Secondly, you try to call the constructor as a static method.

You should do e.g.

```
AES c(AES::AES_128, k);
```

That declares `c` as a variable of type `AES`, and you can use the member functions in the class like

```
c.encryptBlock(someArray, someOtherArray);
```

---

It seems to me that you need to learn some basic (and I mean *really* basic) C++. I suggest you check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you - and you're certainly right on the last point. I have Savitch, but haven't read the chapters on (or used C++ for) OOP yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope the enum

```
AES crypt = AES(AES_TYPE::AES_128, k);
```

Also to encrypt/decrypt you need to use the following functions, respectively.

```
void AES::encryptBlock(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in);
void AES::decryptBlock(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in);
```

So you would call it from your `crypt` object, for example

```
crypt.encryptBlock();
```